# Can you 'extend' form classes?

Tags: php, symfony

I am [creating form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes) for my forms, but cannot figure out how to 'extend' them.

For example, I have a `CustomerType` form class, and an `EmailType` form class. I could add the `EmailType` directly into my `CustomerType`

```
$builder->add('emails', 'collection', array(
    'type'         => new EmailType(),
    'allow_add'    => true,
    'by_reference' => false
));
```

but I'd prefer to do this in the controller, so that my `CustomerType` form class contains only customer information. I feel this is more modular and reusable, since sometimes I want my user to be able to edit only `Customer` details, and others both `Customer` details as well as `Email` objects associated with that customer. (For example, in the first case when viewing a customer's work order, and in the second when creating a new customer).

Is this possible? I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
$form = $this->createForm(new CustomerType(), $customer);
$form->add('emails', 'collection', ...)
```

in my controller.

Comment: Why would it be reusable? If you had two the same forms and were to rename emails field, you'd do it in two places. What is your goal?

Comment: I clarified in the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an option (say "with_email_edition") to your form when it's created that would tell if the form should embed the collection or not.

**In the Controller:**

```
$form = $this->createForm( new CustomerType(), $customerEntity, array('with_email_edition' => true) );
```

**In the form:**

Just add the option in the setDefaultOptions:

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
     $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'with_email_edition' => null,
            ))
            ->setAllowedValues(array(
                'with_email_edition' => array(true, false),
            ));
}
```

and then check in the "buildForm" the value of this option,and add a field based on it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     if( array_key_exists("with_email_edition", $options) && $options['with_email_edition'] === true )
     {
          //Add a specific field with  $builder->add for example
     }
}
```